# LINUX : How to LIMIT incoming (concurrent) connection COUNT?

Tags: linux, count, connection, limit

I'm using RHEL or CentOS. I just want to know how to limit the concurrent/simultaneous connection counts.

Lets say:

- I have a Media Streaming Server
- (According to the Server Performance) I want my Server to be strictly serving to only 100 Viewers at a time. (Only 100 Viewers can be Viewing/ Downloading from my Server)

Is it possible and how to do it please?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the iptables rate limiting feature:

http://codingfreak.blogspot.com/2010/01/iptables-rate-limit-incoming.html

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --hitcount 50 -j DROP
```

Comment: Woww thats great with `iptables`. Ok! And, is that only solution? Or is there any other alternative rather then `iptables`?

Comment: @シリウス check out www.shorewall.net :-)